# Allow change tags in Improve/Reject and edit interface

Tags: feature-request, tags, editing-help

Regarding this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25249896

While adding syntax highlighting does improve the readability of the code in the post, my personal preference is to affect this change through adding the `java` tag to the post, therefore all code blocks would be interpreted as java by default.

My first reaction is to improve the edit because it's a good idea, just implemented the wrong way, except that in the improve editor, I cannot change the tag. So then I tried reject and edit but still I cannot change tags.

The reason I don't want to straight up accept the edit is that while highlighting helps, in this change the code now has an additional indent, which in mobile views makes the overall change potentially worse.

What I am forced to do instead is manually copy the code blocks into an external code editor so I can bulk reduce the tab level, then paste back in. While I can do this, and I do for many posts, there are a lot of code blocks in this post, so there is a greater chance that I'm going to make a mistake.

An alternative is to accept or reject the edit, wait for the resolution then re-edit the post by adding a new tag. I can't edit this tag while a pending edit is being resolved. For one or two posts that I care enough about I will do this but I don't have the time or energy to do this for every post where simply changing the tag would have resolved the issue in a m ore concise manner.

So if we could please allow editing of Tags as an option for Improve/Reject edit interface, even when the suggested change did not involve a tag change this would allow us to maintain more technically/structurally correct posts, given that such a high percentage of edits are simply around code blocks and syntax highlighting and tags greatly affect syntax highlighting.

Comment: In the referenced edit, not all code blocks would be fixed by adding the `java` tag, but if would have affected most of them, leaving only the xml snippet to need specific language annotation.

Comment: Of course you can't change the tag, that post is an *answer*, only questions have tags, on suggested edits to *questions* you already *can* change tags. If you think the edit should've been a tag edit to the question, go to the question and edit it to add the tag (if approriate) and reject the edit, otherwise if the tag wouldn't be appropriate on the question, appove the edit to add the highlighting to the answer in isolation

Comment: So right, totally missed that one, even though I've seen this response on a previous post... agh, sorry guys.